# Toast Notification parameters in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-sdk

Okay so I'm using the new ToastNotificationManager in my 8.1 SL project instead of the old ShellToast. The ShellToast had NavigationUri on the toast message which made it really easy.

In the new toasts you have to specify the launch parameters by yourself according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868212%28v=win.10%29.aspx) article. However it seems like 8.1 SL doesn't have the event *OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)* you are supposed to listen for in App.xaml.cs for the parameters:

> Step 2: Handle the app's "OnLaunched" event
>
> When the user clicks on your toast or selects it through touch, the
>   associated app is launched, firing its OnLaunched event.
>
> Note  If you do not include a launch attribute string in your toast
>   and your app is already running when the toast is selected, the
>   OnLaunched event is not fired.
>
> This example shows the syntax for the override of the OnLaunched
>   event, in which you will retrieve and act on the launch string
>   supplied through the toast notification.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    string launchString = args.Arguments

    ....
}
```

My code:

```
// Using the ToastText02 toast template.
ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;

// Retrieve the content part of the toast so we can change the text.
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

//Find the text component of the content
XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

// Set the text on the toast. 
// The first line of text in the ToastText02 template is treated as header text, and will be bold.
toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Heading"));
toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Body"));

// Set the duration on the toast
IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

//Launch params
string paramString = "{\"type\":\"toast\",\"param1\":\"12345\"}";
((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast")).SetAttribute("launch", paramString);

// Create the actual toast object using this toast specification.
ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

// Set SuppressPopup = true on the toast in order to send it directly to action center without 
// producing a popup on the user's phone.
toast.SuppressPopup = true;

// Send the toast.
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: You can provide the toast with a navigation parameter directly. I'll get the details when I get back to work tomorrow. Odd we haven't documented this properly.

Comment: Thanks looking forward to it! :)

Comment: If you are using the ToastNotificationManager in Silverlight 8.1, what are you using instead of the OnLoaded event since SL doesn't have that in the App.xaml? I have it in the OnNavigatedTo, but it seems to call it twice when the toast is clicked I use the answer for the load trigger below.??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is you're setting the wrong `launch` parameter. You should set it directly to the page you want to navigate to.

```
var toastNavigationUriString = ""#/MainPage.xaml?param1=12345";
var toastElement = ((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast"));
toastElement.SetAttribute("launch", toastNavigationUriString);
```

Comment: Where do you need to define `protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)` method in WP 8.1 SilverLight app? (In App.xaml.cs it says no method to override)

Comment: @ShishirGupta You don't, that method is used exclusively for Universal Apps. For Silverlight 8.1, you just pass it a full uri, directly to the page you want to enter, as per my example.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen What if we don't want to navigate to any page but want to send some data using toast ?

Comment: @loop You must *always* navigate to a page in your app when a toast is clicked. Otherwise it won't pass certification.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen thanks Claus , one more thing - data should be passed in the uri as parameter right ?

Comment: Given it's cross-process, that's effectively your only option.

Comment: How to handle in JavaScript or Windows Runtime Component class in Windows Phone 8.1?