# Selecting a Notification from the Windows Phone 8.1 Action Center

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I am sending Toast Notifications to the device like this.

```
private void SendNotification(string text, string activatedargs = null) {
    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);

    XmlNodeList elements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    foreach(IXmlNode node in elements) {
        node.InnerText = text;
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(activatedargs)) {
        ((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast")).SetAttribute("launch", activatedargs);
    }

    ToastNotification notification = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    notification.Activated += notification_Activated;
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
}
```

As you can see, I am adding a callback function for the Activated event. This works great while the toast notification popup is present at the top of the screen. But when the notification fades away and the notification is only visible in the Action Center, the callback is never called when the notification is selected. The app opens up just fine, but not to a view with information based on the notification that was selected.

So if I have sent three toast notifications, "A", "B", and "C". And these three notifications were listed in the Action Center below my apps name. When the taps on notification "B" specifically, how do I open the app to a view related specifically to "B"?

Comment: See this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275723/toast-notification-parameters-in-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight

This must help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your `activatedargs` to include the identification "A", "B", or "C".

```
activatedargs = "B"
```

then in App.xaml.cs you can get the identification and based on that, navigate to the correct view

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    string launchString = launchEventArgs.Arguments;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(launchString))
    {
        // Get the identification and navigate to correct view
        switch(launchString)
        {
            case "B": NavigateToViewModel<BViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```